# bower-rails can't install packages anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rake, npm, bower

No idea why but a current already bower-rails installed project can't do bower:install anymore !

As it worked before, I already have packages installed locally. 
No idea wht is going one. NO changes as been made !

Tried to reinstall npm and bower, no changes !

```
rake bower:install
bower.js files generated
/usr/local/bin/bower install -p 
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package dsl-generated dependencies=./vendor/assets/bower.json not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/bower install -p ...]

Tasks: TOP => bower:install:production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I **DO** have a bower.json in my /vendor/assets/ directory.

npm -v
1.4.14

bower -v
1.3.11

Here is the full trace:

```
rake bower:install --trace
** Invoke bower:install (first_time)
** Execute bower:install
** Invoke bower:install:production (first_time)
** Execute bower:install:production
bower.js files generated
/usr/local/bin/bower install -p 
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package dsl-generated dependencies=./vendor/assets/bower.json not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/bower install -p ...]
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:54:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/tasks/bower.rake:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:32:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in dsl_perform_command'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:56:in `chdir'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:56:in `block in dsl_perform_command'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:55:in `dsl_perform_command'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:31:in `perform'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/bower-rails/performer.rb:10:in `perform'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/tasks/bower.rake:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bower-rails-0.8.3/lib/tasks/bower.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
./bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => bower:install:production
```

Same when I try to `rake bower:list`

```
rake bower:list     
/usr/local/bin/bower list
bower check-new     Checking for new versions of the project dependencies..
bower ENOTFOUND     Package dsl-generated dependencies=./vendor/assets/bower.json not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/bower list...]

Tasks: TOP => bower:list
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: does `./vendor/assets/bower.json` still exist?

Comment: Yes, that's what makes me crazy.
And if I delete it, rake bower:install recreates it.

Comment: I've had this same issue with bower-rails. And I didn't make any changes either! No idea how it started happening. The only way around it was to delete the app and redeploy from scratch

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too late, but I'll leave it here, since I had similar issues using **bower-rails**, when running:

```
rake bower:install.
```

The solution I found on the web is running:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Hope it's helpful for someone else in the same situation.

Comment: I had the same issue as @gdurelle, but unfortunately this answer didn't fix the problem. I wasn't able to workout a solution other than deleting my app and re-deploying from scratch

Comment: worked for me.  Nothing at all in bower worked for me until I did that.  If I remember right, I've had issues before with programs expecting the node executable to be nodejs instead of node, and the way I solved it before was just to create a symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

you can install nodejs by nvm, apt-get can't install all packages of nodejs.

1. `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash`
2. `source ~/.profile`
3. `nvm install v0.12.7`
4. `npn install bower -g`
5. `rake bower:install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, our codebase used private Bower packages hosted on Gemfury. We enabled this by adding

  `"resolvers": [
    "fury-bower-resolver"
  ]`

to the repo's `.bowerrc`. This setting is only supported in Bower 1.7.x. My global `bower` binary was 1.7.2, so I had no problems running `bower install`, but the `rake bower:install` tasks doesn't use my global `bower`; it uses `my_repo/node_modules/.bin/bower` instead, and that one was version 1.4.2, which didn't understand the `resolvers` setting, hence the 'package not found' error. You can see which binary it's using in one of the first log output lines; then you can invoke that binary with `-v` to see which version it's on. The fix was to upgrade the Bower binary that bower-rails uses with `npm upgrade bower` (needless to say, don't add the `-g` option!)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `vendor` directory and re-running `rake bower:install`.

P.S. Before deleting please check what else is inside `vendor` directory besides `bower_components` - you may have to reinstall those as well.